# Regex to match OPO Invite link

Tags: php, regex

```
if (preg_match('#^https?://account.oneplus.net/invite/claim/....-....-....-....#', $url) === 0) {
    return "Invalid link";
}
```

I currently use this code (in PHP) to verify the url. However, it also passes as true when you try with other stuff trailing behind the link. How do I fix this so that only links ending with or without / work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the regex I was looking for:

```
preg_match('#^https?://account.oneplus.net/invite/claim/\S{4}-\S{4}-\S{4}-\S{4}/?$#', $url) === 0
```

Comment: You edited your answer :) But it's good now, so you can have those points ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace all the dots with `\S` (*which matches any non-space character*), so `....` would be written as `\S{4}` because `.` would match also a horizontal space. And also add the pattern (`/?`) to match an optional `/` at the last.

Comment: Okay, I've made that change. Thank you. Now how do I fix the fact that it's  matching when there are more characters behind the link?